# What am I doing wrong in mocking this method?

Tags: java, testng, mockito

Here's a snippet of my test class.

```
class MyClassTest {
    MyClass my;
    HandlerA handlerA;
    HandlerB handlerB

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {

        handlerA = mock(HandlerA.class);
        handlerB = mock(HandlerB.class);
        my = new MyClass(handlerA, handlerB);
    }

    @Test
    public void testhandlerABuilderNegativeCase() {

        Shapes s = getShapes();
        Types t = my.buildTypes();
        when(handlerA.handle(s, t)).thenReturn(Response.status(500).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());//ineffective.

        Assert.assertFalse(my.handlerABuilder());
    }

    Shapes getShapes() {
        //returns shapes;
    }
}
```

Here is my main class.

```
public class MyClass {

    MyClass(HandlerA handleA, HandlerB handleB) {
        this.handleA= handleA;
        this.handleB= handleB;
    }
    ...
    boolean handlerABuilder() {
        Types t = buildTypes();
        Shapes s = getShapes();
        Response resp = handleA.handle(s,t);// resp is always null. despite using when to set 
        return (resp.getStatus==200); // throws NPE
    }
    Types buildTypes(){
        //return types.
    }

    Shapes getShapes() {
        //return shapes.
    }
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException`, because the `when` does not seem to be executing correctly. As a result the response is always returned as null. Any thoughts on why this could be happening? I've tried debugging as well, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Ideally, provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It'd be nice if we had something that was a little bit more compilable.

Comment: Sorry about that. Ive abstracted away most of the stuff as this is happening on production code. Its a bad excuse yes. But I believe Ive provided enough context to the issue. Feel free to ask if you need clarification

Comment: I can respect that it's for production code, but giving us something that's abstracted out and *compilable* will go a long way towards us helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you care what's being passed to `handle`?  You're mocking the result of it *anyway*, so there's no reason to worry about passing anything specific to it.

What's likely happening is that you're passing in `null` to it, and that isn't being handled very well.

What you can do is change your `when` condition to match on `any` object instead.

```
when(handlerA.handle(any(Shapes.class), any(Types.class)))
   .thenReturn(Response.status(500).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
```

Comment: This fixed it. But Im pretty sure I was actually passing non null actual values. Dont real values work when passing them as parameters for mocking in the `when`?

Comment: They would work if you weren't instantiating them in the class. That's actually why it's not working; I'll correct my answer soon.